# Office-JS API: Sending large array of table data to MVC controller

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, office-js

I am developing an add-in for Office 2016 and office 365 online using the Office Javascript API. As a requirement I need to parse all rows and columns from a worksheet table and send it to the server for processing. I have achieved this through standard ajax POST call by parsing the range values to JSON string values as a two-dimensional array. This works but only up to a certain size and fails when the cell count exceeds 1.000.000. However, the add-in must support import of table data exceeding 100's thousands of rows with 20+ columns.

Client code:

```
var table = tables.getItemAt(0);
var tableRange = table.getRange();
tableRange.load("values");
ctx.sync().then(function () {
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        traditional: true,
        data: JSON.stringify({ values: tableRange.values }),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        url: "/Import/ProcessImport",
        success: function (response) { writeInfoMessage(response.responseText); },
        error: function () { writeErrorMessage("/Import/ProcessImport Failed!") }
    });
});
```

Server code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ProcessImport(string[][] values)
{
    //TODO: Process the values data here
    var result = "Success";
    return Json(new {success = true, responseText = result});
}
```

I have been trying to play around with the aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers value in the Web.config and although it works up to a certain limit it seems to fail when exceeding 1.000.000 cells regardless of how high I put the number.

Web.Config

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="1500000" />
</appSettings>
```

I also know it is bad practice to extend the maximum item number for Json to high quantities like this, but I am unable to see any other way around sending such large datasets from the client to the server, unless I am missing the obvious?

Comment: If you passing a very large JSON object exceeding the max deserialization size, I suggest figuring out a way to break the JSON in two requests. Maybe half gets processed first then the next half.. Since you are using JavaScript, things will run asynchronously which helps when you are breaking tasks into smaller ones.

Comment: Hi Ephraim. That has crossed my mind as well and I will probably have to look into breaking the requests down into chunks if there is no real good way to process the request all at once. Thanks for your reply :-)

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: Stephen, thanks for pointing that out. I am fairly new to posting at Stack Overflow and will keep that in mind next time.